# Horizontal clipping of content in iframe

Tags: iframe

I have an iframe in a page that has a menu in it with drop downs and horizontal flyouts.  The menu has 4 levels of navigation. Problem is for the menu item furthest to the right, the flyouts are cut off by the div that holds the iframe. The css overflow for the div and the iframe is set to visble. There is no position set for the div, the z-index for the div is 9999, but the menu is still clipped at the edge of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the z-index property set on that div if it's not positioned being that 
the z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
But z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

If anything, the menu ought to have a high z-index value set.